# jQuery ajax JSON response too big

Tags: ajax, json, web-services

I have a .NET web service that returns a `string` to a jQuery `$.ajax` call.

If the string's length is less than 88900 (or so) it works fine, but as soon as I add 100 more characters to the string, it does not work anymore. I get a `500 Internal Server` error.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

jQuery doesn't limit the size, but ASP.NET does by default.  You can adjust it with this web.config setting:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="x">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the max length of you Json result.

```
var list = Json(new { list = tasksList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

list.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
```